# $f(x) < g(x) \Rightarrow \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx < \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx \ $. Why not in both directions?

Tags: integration

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on the interval $\left[ a,b\right]$ and $a<b$

$ f(x) < g(x)  \Rightarrow \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx < \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx \ $ for $x \in \left[ a,b\right]$

Why doesn't the statement apply in the other direction?

$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx < \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx \ \not\Rightarrow  f(x) < g(x)$

Comment: Because a small change of a function changes the integral small, but the small change of the function would have a great change for the differentiation.

Comment: An integral over a given interval is a mean value (up to a multiplicative constant determined by the length of the interval). A higher mean value does not mean that all values are higher.

Comment: Consider $f_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon \sin (x/\epsilon^2)$; We have $|f_\epsilon| < \epsilon$, but $-1/\epsilon <f_\epsilon'(x) < 1/\epsilon$; You can have very small $\epsilon$ to get big $|f'|$.

Comment: @Chrystomath woops I think you're right I mixed up the antiderivative and derivative

Comment: Assume that this true $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx < \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx \ \Rightarrow  f(x) < g(x)$. Show that such an assumption cannot hold.

Comment: I have a better counter example, take $2x$ and $1-x$ from $0$ to $1$. Just because one accumulates more area doesn't mean that the inequality holds over the whole interval.

Comment: You can see my answer, hopefully it's very simple and makes sense

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx < \int_a^b g(x)\,dx$ for *all* pairs $a,b$ with $a < b$, then you can at least conclude that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$.  (But for a counterexample if you try to conclude $f(x) < g(x)$ everywhere: consider $f(x) \equiv 0$ and $g(x) = x^2$.)

Comment: Because counterexample

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen out of all the comments and answers (including my own), this is by far my favourite thing on this post........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this could happen (same reasoning as the other answer):

[image: a sharp red bump-like function poking just above a constant blue function at one point]

Answer (score 1):

Intuitive answer: because of width. A function could go to a very large value for a very small interval and the area will be still very small. For example, consider
$$
f(x) = \{x \in [0,0.5]: 0; x \in (0.5,1] : 10\}
$$
(in other words, ${f(x)}$ is $0$ when ${0\leq x \leq 0.5}$, and ${f(x)=10}$ when ${0.5< x \leq 1}$) easily you can see
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = 10\times 0.5 = 5
$$
Now consider
$$
g(x) = 6
$$
then ${\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx=6}$. So ${\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx < \int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx}$; however, clearly ${f(x)}$ is not smaller than ${g(x)}$ as ${f(x)}$ takes on the value ${10}$, which is greater than $6$.

Comment: Don't you mean $ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx < \int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx $ ?

Comment: @VeNETHER sorry yes, I'll correct the typo now